# How to Use document.getElementById with Multiple IDs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change the code of both the button after clicking it work fine when I use single id but when I use multiple id it did not work I am still learning js so any idea will be helpfull

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('copy_btn','down_btn');
copy_btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  btn.innerHTML = `<iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon> Copied`;
});
down_btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  btn.innerHTML = `<iconify-icon icon="ri:file-download-line"></iconify-icon> Downloading`;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- iconify cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.0/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="down_btn"><iconify-icon icon="ri:file-download-line"></iconify-icon> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"   onclick="copyEvent();" id="copy_btn"><iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon> Copy </button>
```

Comment: You cannot use it with multiple IDs. Try `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: `const copy_btn = document.getElementById('copy_btn'), down_btn = document.getElementById('down_btn');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach, define a function `addClickHandlers` which takes in an array of elements (each element has an id, icon and text) and then adds click handlers for each element.

```js
const addClickHandlers = (ids) => {
  ids.forEach(({ id, icon, text }) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.addEventListener("click", function handleClick() {
      element.innerHTML = `<iconify-icon icon="${icon}"></iconify-icon> ${text}`;
    });
  });
};

addClickHandlers([
  { id: "copy_btn", icon: "akar-icons:copy", text: "Copied" },
  { id: "down_btn", icon: "ri:file-download-line", text: "Downloading" },
]);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.0/iconify-icon.min.js"></script><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="down_btn"><iconify-icon icon="ri:file-download-line"></iconify-icon> Download</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="copyEvent();" id="copy_btn"><iconify-icon icon="akar-icons:copy"></iconify-icon> Copy </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hint is in the name `getElementById` "element" meaning singular.
you can use `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`.

but if they have different ID's then you have do it two times.

`const downBtn = document.getElementById("down_btn");`

`const copyBtn = document.getElementById("copy_btn");`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` only supports one name at a time and only returns a single node not an array of nodes. You have several different options:

- You could implement your own function that takes multiple ids and returns multiple elements.
- You could use `document.querySelectorAll()` that allows you to specify multiple ids in a CSS selector string .
- You could put a common class names on all those nodes and use `document.getElementsByClassName()` with a single class name.

Try like this:

```
document.getElementById("copy_btn down_btn");
```